# Selenium - download multiple files stopped unexpectedly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

sorry if this question is going to sound stupid for some of you but I'm new to selenium and I'm trying to figurate out it.

---

**SYSTEM:**

**Python**: 3.8

**Selenium**: 3.141.0

**Chromedevice**: 81.0

---

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO:**

I'm trying to do a script that is going to download some data from WCRP CORDEX [webiste](https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/search/cordex-dkrz/)

Those are my steps:

- Choose some filters
- Display 100 results
- Press search
- Press on each element the button **THREDDS Catalog**
- Download all files **".nc"** from all of the those pages

---

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I'm trying to download multiple files, always it happened that some of those files are going to get interrupted out of nowhere. How can I do that in the ChromeDriver from Selenium I'm not going to get any interrupted downloads? Or if I'm getting some interrupted files, how can I start them again automatically?

---

**MY CODE:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def wait_until(by, element_id):
    timeout = 5
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((by, element_id))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for page to load")


OpenID = "<OPEN_ID>"
password = "<PASSOWRD>"
baseLink = "https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/search/cordex-dkrz/"
download_path = "<DOWNLOAD_PATH>"

profile = Options()
chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
preferences = {
    "download.default_directory": download_path,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": "false"
}

profile.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=profile)

driver.get(baseLink)

wait_until(By.ID, "checkbox_project_CORDEX")

for e in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("accordionToggleItem"):
    e.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)

driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_project_CORDEX-Adjust").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_product_bias-adjusted-output").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_domain_EUR-11").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_domain_EUR-11i").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_experiment_historical").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_experiment_rcp26").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_experiment_rcp45").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_experiment_rcp85").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_experiment_family_All").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_rcm_name_ARPEGE51").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_rcm_name_CCLM4-8-17").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_rcm_name_HIRHAM5").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_rcm_name_RACMO22E").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_rcm_name_RCA4").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_rcm_name_REMO2009").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_rcm_name_WRF331F").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_time_frequency_day").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_variable_prAdjust").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_variable_tasmaxAdjust").click()
driver.find_element_by_id(
    "checkbox_variable_long_name_Bias-Adjusted Daily Maximum Near-Surface Air Temperature").click()
driver.find_element_by_id(
    "checkbox_variable_long_name_Bias-Adjusted Daily Minimum Near-Surface Air Temperature").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_variable_long_name_Bias-Adjusted Near-Surface Air Temperature").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_variable_long_name_Bias-Adjusted Precipitation").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_cf_standard_name_air_temperature").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_cf_standard_name_daily_maximum_near-surface_temperature_maximum").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_cf_standard_name_daily_minimum_near-surface_temperature_minimum").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_cf_standard_name_precipitation").click()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('limit'))
select.select_by_visible_text('100')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Search']").click()

thredds = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("THREDDS Catalog")
thredds_links = []
for t in thredds:
    thredds_links.append(t.get_attribute('href'))

current_page_ind = 0

check_first_time = False
for thredds_link in thredds_links:
    current_page_ind += 1
    print("PAGE: ", current_page_ind, len(thredds_links))
    driver.get(thredds_link)
    data = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(".nc")
    data_link = [l.get_attribute('href') for l in data]

    current_data_ind = 0
    for link in data_link:
        current_data_ind += 1
        print("LINK: ", current_data_ind, len(data_link))
        driver.get(link)
        wait_until(By.LINK_TEXT, "HTTPServer")

        download_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("HTTPServer").get_attribute('href')
        driver.get(download_link)

        if not check_first_time:
            check_first_time = True
            wait_until(By.CLASS_NAME, "custom-combobox-input")
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("custom-combobox-input").send_keys(OpenID)
            driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitButton").click()
            driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("button").click()
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix this? If so please help me if you know because I need this functionality.

Comment: What version of selenium and chromedriver are you using? Make sure it's the most [up to date](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Comment: please try to add time.sleep(2) to your code specially after each driver.get and see if it will ever change or not... please let me know. Also try to replace wait_until with time.sleep

Comment: @Diggy., I've updated my question and I've added a section with SYSTEM, thanks .

Comment: @Ehsan, I've tried that and it doesn't matter, I'm receiving a download failed even though I've used "time.sleep(2)" and I've tried also with "time.sleep(60*20)". I'm obtaining the same failed each time.